# Light weight way convert Docx to string Using c#

Tags: c#, string, full-text-search, docx

I writing a search program to find strings in HUGE collections of documents

I don't need to edit or view I just need to grab text as a string out of a word Doc (docx) what is easiest / lightest weight option out there?

What I would like to do is slowly start adding modules for diffrent File types

if file ends in docx   string holding = DocxExtract(File) or something like that

```
string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(textBox2.Text, "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories);

foreach (string file in files)
{
    try
    {
        foreach (string line in File.ReadLines(file))
        {
            if (line.Contains(textBox3.Text))
            {
                textBox1.AppendText(file+"\r\n");
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    catch
    { 
    }
}
```

Comment: Extract using 7-Zip/WinRAR/etc, then open document.xml

Comment: @DannyBeckett sorry its late I forgot to mention that I'm doing this in c# (post updated)

Comment: Side note: consider reading on existing systems for similar tasks to learn about potential issues like [Windows search](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff628790(v=vs.85).aspx) which includes [architecture overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/cc678933(v=vs.85).aspx) if you want to check if your design is reasonable.

Comment: Thanks, I considered search for indexing but 1) I don't really need it indexed (im trying to search in realtime just once) and 2) its not on a windows based machine so its hard to have a service run on it.

Comment: @DannyBeckett code added but thanks for pointing that out

Answer (score 0):

this is what I've come up with so far that seems to work

I'm using the [dot net zip dll here](http://dotnetzip.codeplex.com/) extracting the one file i need to a stream then converting the stream to a string.

---

This is very rough and if you have a suggestion please let me know 
(I will wait a day or so to award points if there is a better answer)

```
private bool FindInDocx(string file,string search)
        {

            var ms = new MemoryStream();
            using (ZipFile zip = ZipFile.Read(file))
            {
                ZipEntry a = zip[@"word\document.xml"];
                a.Extract(ms);
            }
            ms.Position = 0;
            var sr = new StreamReader(ms);
            var myStr = sr.ReadToEnd();

            return myStr.Contains(search);

        }
```